# Angular 2 Check if template url exist?

Tags: angular

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-selectb',
 template: `<div  [innerHTML]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.url)">
 </div>`
})

export class SelectComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() abi:string;
url: string;


constructor(public sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {
}

ngOnInit() {
var myId;
var myLanguage;
myId = $("div[name=check]").attr('data-abi');
myLanguage = $("div[name=check]").attr('data-lang');

if(myId==undefined || myId=="" || !(require('./banche/'+myId+'/it/file.html'))){
  myId='default';
}

this.url = require('./banche/'+myId+'/'+myLanguage+'/file.html');
require('style-loader!./banche/'+myId+'/style.css');
}

}
```

I want to know if the html file doesn't exist in the path, the variable myId must become "default" (there is a default path with default name). Thanks :)

Comment: You shouldn't call `sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.url)` in the template. This will be called every time change detection runs. Rather call it it code, assign the result to a field an bind to that field instead.

Comment: I need of sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.url) because without sanititizer i don't see input type text on the page

Comment: I didn't say you shouldn't. I just said you should do it somewhere else. Your code should cause an exception in development mode and cause severe performance issues in production.

Comment: Ah ok, but what i should do ?

Comment: As I said call it in the components class code and assign the result to a field and bind to that field instead.

Comment: How do I do to make it ?

Comment: `this.url = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(myUrl)`, `[innerHTML]="url"`

Comment: Ok thanks, but now how do I do to make that I have asked in my question ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about that.